# Can parameters be variable

Tags: verilog, hdl, quartus, iverilog, icarus

I know that we can use parameters to make generic modules, and to improve readability of code. My question is whether we can have these parameters themselves as a variable. Something like this:

```
module parameterModule #(parameter p1, ...)(<ports>);
  ...
  ...
endmodule

module changingParameterModule (output [p1_width-1:0] p1);
  ...
  ...
endmodule
```

Here, I want `p1` port of the changingParameterModule to be treated as the parameter `p1` for the parameterModule. Is this possible?

I use icarus-verilog and Quartus Prime Lite.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible; parameters are compile time constants. Module port outputs have the potential to change at any time, and their values don't even get computed until after compilation is over.

Comment: Thanks! I actually want them to change. I'm trying to make a memory unit that doesn't have a fixed size, until I get the user input.